# Prevent to running common events in React Navigation stack screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Screens.Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Blog" component={Screens.Blog} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

When I Navigate to `Blog stack` some of the events(such as `BackHandler` ,`open keyboard when focus on Textinput` ,...) in this screen affect the `Home screen`.

How can a new Screen work as a stand-alone Screen in Stack Navigation?

---

*If my question is raised incorrectly, please help me edit my question*

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the gestureEnabled property to false to prevent default back events other options are available to prohibit native activated events.

If you want to remove the header you can do it by attributing null for the headerMode property to null